# React and Gatsby: apply css/js masonry to some pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby, masonry

I know very little about React, just trying to get a Gatsby portfolio going, with an index page and a template that makes tagged pages. I wanted to apply this css/js masonry to my index and tagged pages https://codepen.io/didumos/pen/xNPKRJ

But I'm not sure what the best approach is. Would I want to break the JS out into a utils.js file, and import it to index.js and taggedtemplate.js? It's pretty long and has some on load/on refresh functions. A coworker told me to use hooks but not sure how.

any advice appreciated! thank you!

oh stackoverflow is telling me I need to past code in when linking to a codepen. Here's the JS adapted from that codepen.

```
const minColWidth = 500;
let roots;

function onLoad() {
  var rootElements = document.getElementsByClassName('indexWrapper');
  roots = Array.prototype.map.call(rootElements, function(rootElement) {
    var cellElements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName('item');
    var cells = Array.prototype.map.call(cellElements, function(cellElement) {
      var style = getComputedStyle(cellElement);
      return {
        'element': cellElement,
        'outerHeight': parseInt(style.marginTop) + cellElement.offsetHeight + parseInt(style.marginBottom)
      };
    });
    return {
      'element': rootElement,
      'noOfColumns': 0,
      'cells': cells
    };
  });

  // do the first layout
  onResize();
}

function onResize() {
  for (let root of roots) {
    // only layout when the number of columns has changed
    var newNoOfColumns = Math.floor(root.element.offsetWidth / minColWidth);
    if (newNoOfColumns != root.noOfColumns) {

      // initialize
      root.noOfColumns = newNoOfColumns;
      var columns = Array.from(new Array(root.noOfColumns)).map( function(column) {
        return {
          'cells': new Array(),
          'outerHeight': 0
        };
      });

      // divide...
      for (let cell of root.cells) {
        var minOuterHeight = Math.min(...columns.map( function(column) {
          return column.outerHeight;
        }));
        var column = columns.find( function(column) {
          return column.outerHeight == minOuterHeight;
        });
        column.cells.push(cell);
        column.outerHeight += cell.outerHeight;
      }

      // calculate masonry height
      var masonryHeight = Math.max(...columns.map( function(column) {
        return column.outerHeight;
      }));

      // ...and conquer
      var order = 0;
      for (let column of columns) {
        for (let cell of column.cells) {
          cell.element.style.order = order++;
          // set the cell's flex-basis to 0
          cell.element.style.flexBasis = 0;
        }
        // set flex-basis of the last cell to fill the
        // leftover space at the bottom of the column
        // to prevent the first cell of the next column
        // to be rendered at the bottom of this column
        column.cells[column.cells.length - 1].element.style.flexBasis = column.cells[column.cells.length - 1].element.offsetHeight + masonryHeight - column.outerHeight - 1 + 'px';
      }

      // set the masonry height to trigger
      // re-rendering of all cells over columns
      // one pixel more than the tallest column
      root.element.style.maxHeight = masonryHeight + 1 + 'px';

      console.log(columns.map( function(column) {
        return column.outerHeight;
      }));
      console.log(root.element.style.maxHeight);
    }
  }
}

// subscribe to load and resize events
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be precise here because I'm not sure what the exact problem is. But looking at the code, you seem to need to take smaller steps on your journey into react. You would want to avoid dom queries and dom manipulations as much as possible, this would include `getElementsByClassName`, which every beginner knows, but using it in the context of react is mostly going to give you pain.

Your colleauge was right about hooks, and you should use them whenever you have `addEventListener` going on, you would want to wrap them in useEffect to prevent hundreds or thousands of `addEventListener` to be executed.

There's a gatsby plugin for emotion which I use a lot for css. But searching about masonry, I doubt that it's designed for react, except there's a specific plugin for it, then you may have more luck there. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: Sorry my question was a bit vague, I guess I'm asking how do I break that code into hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code you posted I see that you have two functions that you can use with React Hooks: `onLoad` and `onResize`.
onLoad method should be used inside `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook if you're exporting your component as class or `React.useEffect()` if you're exporting it as a function. That way your masonry javascript code will fire right after the DOM is rendered.
As for reloading your msonry layout when resizing, you can use `window.addEventListener('resize', onResize)` inside the lifecycle hooks mentioned above.